# Запятые перед "либо"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

По какому правилу нужно или не нужно ставить запятые перед "либо" в следующем предложении:

> Это может быть отельный эпизод, в котором вы описываете, что конкретно вы сделали и на сколько это увеличило монетизацию, либо скорость роста, либо любой другой важный параметр для приложения.

И верно ли написано "на сколько"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перед союзом "либо" запятая нужна. В предложении три однородных члена (эпизод, скорость, параметр), соединенных  союзом либо, который повторяется  два раза. В этом случае после каждого однородного члена ставится запятая. В Вашем примере запятые расставлены верно.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае раздельно - присутствуют определения (скорость, параметр), поэтому явно числительное. Вот если бы было "При отеле монетизация увеличилась настолько, насколько снизился удой" (тут больше союз) :)

Comment: Спасибо! Еще такой вопрос:  "числительное" - это образное выражение? Я бы сказал, что числительных в предложении не наблюдаю =)

Comment: насколько, нареч. (насколько можно судить), но числит. на сколько (на сколько дней)
Это с грамоты.ру (но в комментариях, насколько я понял, ссылок ставить нельзя).

Answer (score 0):

В примере не "отельный эпизод", а "отдельный" :) то есть никак не связанный с отелями ;)
Насчёт "на?сколько" - я бы добавила единицу измерения ("на_сколько процентов") и тогда писала бы раздельно с чистой совестью.
Хотя до сих пор я как-то не задумывалась, как измеряют монетизацию.

Comment: На?сколько (на_сколько) или чем ;) отличается от :)?